# Moving file in the same location different folder in SSIS

Tags: ssis

How can I move files from one folder to another folder in SSIS using File System Task?

Example:

Move
D:\Target_folder files into D:\Target_folder\Old

here all the files in Target_folder like .xls,.txt will move into Old.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a number of variables with datatype of string

```
name   : value
dstDir : D:\Target_folder\Old 
srcDir : D:\Target_folder

FileName : 
srcPath : [this should be an expression concating srcDir and FileName]
dstPath :[this should be an expression concating dstDir and FileName]
```

You then add a for each `loop` container then double click on it to open up the editor and choose collections.

Make sure the enumerator is a `foreach File Enumurator`. Click on the Expressions ellipsis underneath this and set the Directory property to srcPath.

Go to Variable Mappings add the `User::FileName` variable to map to the 0 index.

Add a `File System Task` to the for each loop container.

Set the operation to Move file

set both `IsDestinationPathVariable` and `IsSourcePathVariable` to `true` and set the values for `DestinationVariable` to `dstPath` and the `SourceVariable` to `srcPath`.

This should enumerate for each file in the directory source directory and move it to your destination directory.

Comment: I am able to do it only for a single .txt or .xls file but when i want to add multiple or everything except old file then all the file move into old and inside old folder there also creates another Old folder.

Comment: You have to put the the File System Task inside the for each loop container. Also make sure you are select name and extension within the for each loop container and not the whole path.  this is set in the For each loop editor in on the collection screen (retrieve file name)

Comment: Can u tell me what will be the expression to concat. 
I write @[User::srcdir] +"\\" + @[User::filename] but not work properly

Comment: That should be fine. Do you have the variable property, EvaluateAsExpression, set to true?

Comment: yes.

[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Illegal characters in path.".

this error occured.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the for each loop container, choose break at the beginning of each iteration of the loop and then check what values you are getting for FileName as well as for scrPath and dstPath.

Comment: Be aware you can do this with a simple command line command that bears a lot of resemblance to your question: `MOVE D:\Target_folder\*.* D:\Target_folder\Old`. No loops or variables required.

Comment: when I D:\Target_folder\file.xls it moved

but when D:\Target_folder\*.* it not worked.